# DRIconf for 12.04

Tags: 12.04, grub2, configuration, intel-graphics, 3d

I'm having problems on 3d acceleration on Ubuntu 12.04 that I hadn't have before on 11.10. I've an Intel HD graphics, what can I do??

I've downloaded  DRIconf, I used it on 11.10 and it worked great.

But now not sure why it's a bit buggy. Does anyone know a good configuration for DRI? 
Im getting also this error, `[ 7.649228] intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: failed to get i915 symbols`

But just for half a second on boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> failed to get i915 symbols

Sounds like a kernel option that needs to be set.You can try if setting the modeset is the fix for this from within grub before making it permanent:

- hold down shift when the grub booting screen is showing
- Press `e` (for edit)
- add `i915.modeset=1` to the end of the line (it probably currently ends with `splash`)
- press control-x to boot

If this works you can set it permanently from command line with ...

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i915.modeset=1"
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: not working, anyway I think I might do a clean install AGAIN..XD